# Realize a console in a GTK3 GUI programming in C

Tags: c, console, gtk3

I realized a GUI with GTK3 that, essentially, generates an input text file for an exe program that with these inputs can do elaborations.
This exe is put in executions in the GUI by mean of a System call ( system("exe input.dat  &") ).

This exe can print on screen message of information or error.

What I want to do is redirect these message on a GtkTextView.

The idea that I had is to redirect output and error on a file ( system("exe  input.dat > output_file.txt 2>&1 &") ) and in the GUI read line by line this 
file and send this strings in the textView.

I was not sure that 2 process can write and read the same file and to test this concept I used these 2 simple programs:
the writer (used like ./writer > out_file.txt):

```
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <unistd.h>

      main()
      {
         int a;

         while(1)
         {
            fprintf(stdout,"a=%d\n",a);
            fflush(stdout);
            sleep(1);
            a++;
         }
      }
```

and the reader:

```
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <string.h>

      int main()
      {
         FILE *fp;
         fp = fopen("out_file.txt","r");
         char string_new[1024];
         char string_old[1024];
         strcpy(string_old," ");

         while(1)
         {
            fgets(string_new,1024,fp);
            if ( strlen(string_new) != 0 )
            {
               if ( strcmp(string_new, string_old) != 0 )
               {
                  fprintf(stdout,"%s",string_new);
                  fflush(stdout);
                  strcpy(string_old,string_new);
               }
            }
         }
      }
```

This two programs run correctly and the second one print the output of the first one.

Putting in the GUI a similar code, the GUI read only the first line of the file.

How I can solve this issue?
Thank you

Comment: You need to improve your answer to tell a lot more about your `exe` program.

Comment: Without more information about that  `exe` program your question is unclear. Is that `exe` program always running very quickly (in a fraction of a second) like e.g. some `ps` command?

Comment: The exe program is designed to performs the measurement of a physical variable. After the configuration of several instruments via LAN, it start to make measurements. The time needed to ends all measurements is, more or less, about 1 hour. What I want displays on the console is something like: "Total N. points of measurements 1000" "Measured 3 points of 1000" "Measured 4 points of 1000" etc.

Comment: That should go in the question

Comment: I have rollbacked your heavy changes to the question after it got answered twice. Please do not include a solution in your question itself: instead, post your own answer (or edit the deleted one that you already made, then flag it for undeletion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`popen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) instead of executing `system("exe input.dat &")`, then it's easy to read from the `stdout` output of the program.

Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = popen("ls -lah /tmp", "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
        return 1;

    char buffer[1024];

    int linecnt = 0;
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp))
        printf("Line: %d: %s", ++linecnt, buffer);

    putchar('\n');
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
$ ./b 
Line: 1: total 108K
Line: 2: drwxrwxrwt  8 root    root     12K Mar 10 02:30 .
Line: 3: drwxr-xr-x 26 root    root    4.0K Feb 15 01:05 ..
Line: 4: -rwxr-xr-x  1 shaoran shaoran  16K Mar  9 22:29 a
Line: 5: -rw-r--r--  1 shaoran shaoran 3.6K Mar  9 22:29 a.c
Line: 6: -rw-------  1 shaoran shaoran  16K Mar  9 22:29 .a.c.swp
Line: 7: -rwxr-xr-x  1 shaoran shaoran  11K Mar 10 02:30 b
Line: 8: -rw-r--r--  1 shaoran shaoran  274 Mar 10 02:30 b.c
Line: 9: -rw-------  1 shaoran shaoran  12K Mar 10 02:30 .b.c.swp
Line: 10: drwx------  2 shaoran shaoran 4.0K Mar  9 20:08 firefox_shaoran
Line: 11: drwxrwxrwt  2 root    root    4.0K Mar  9 20:06 .ICE-unix
Line: 12: srwx------  1 mongodb mongodb    0 Mar  9 20:07 mongodb-27017.sock
Line: 13: prwx------  1 shaoran shaoran    0 Mar  9 20:08 oaucipc-c2s-1874
Line: 14: prwx------  1 shaoran shaoran    0 Mar  9 20:08 oaucipc-s2c-1874
Line: 15: drwxrwxr-x  2 root    utmp    4.0K Mar  9 20:06 screen
Line: 16: drwx------  2 shaoran shaoran 4.0K Mar  9 20:07 ssh-XueH0w8zWCSE
Line: 17: drwx------  2 shaoran shaoran 4.0K Mar  9 20:08 thunderbird_shaoran
Line: 18: -r--r--r--  1 root    root      11 Mar  9 20:07 .X0-lock
Line: 19: drwxrwxrwt  2 root    root    4.0K Mar  9 20:07 .X11-unix
```

If you need more control and want also to read `stderr`, then you would have to create pipes for `stdout` and `stderr`,
make a `fork` and the child [`dup2`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) the pipes to `stderr` & `stdout` and
then execute [`exec`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) (or any other function of that family) to execute the
program.

Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{

    int stdout_pipe[2];
    int stderr_pipe[2];

    pipe(stdout_pipe);
    pipe(stderr_pipe);

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if(pid < 0)
        return 1;

    if(pid == 0)
    {
        // closing reading ends and duplicating writing ends
        close(stdout_pipe[0]);
        dup2(stdout_pipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

        close(stderr_pipe[0]);
        dup2(stderr_pipe[1], STDERR_FILENO);

        execlp("ls", "ls", "-alh", "a.c", "kslkdl", NULL);

        exit(1);
    }

    // closing writing end
    close(stdout_pipe[1]);
    close(stderr_pipe[1]);

    int status;

    if(waitpid(pid, &status, 0) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not wait\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(WIFEXITED(status) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ls exited abnormally\n");
        close(stdout_pipe[0]);
        close(stderr_pipe[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    puts("STDOUT:");
    char buffer[1024];

    ssize_t len;
    while((len = read(stdout_pipe[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1)) > 0)
    {
        buffer[len] = 0;
        printf("%s", buffer);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    close(stdout_pipe[0]);

    puts("STDERR:");

    while((len = read(stderr_pipe[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1)) > 0)
    {
        buffer[len] = 0;
        printf("%s", buffer);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    close(stderr_pipe[0]);


    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
$ ./b 
STDOUT:
-rw-r--r-- 1 shaoran shaoran 3.6K Mar  9 22:29 a.c

STDERR:
ls: cannot access 'kslkdl': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Pablo, thank you for your codes. I will try to use them.

Answer (score 2):

[Pablo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49204490/841108) is correct, you need to use [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s.

And you could probably use GTK & Glib's [`g_spawn_async_with_pipes`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html#g-spawn-async-with-pipes) (which is based on `pipe` and  `fork` and `execve` on Linux) for that (instead of `fork` or `popen`). In a GTK interactive program, it is better than the usual `popen` because the forked program would run concurrently with your event loop.

You could even consider using [`g_source_add_unix_fd`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-source-add-unix-fd) on the (or on some) of the pipe fd-s given by [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) or by `g_spawn_async_with_pipes` which use that [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) call. But you might prefer [`g_io_channel_unix_new`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-IO-Channels.html#g-io-channel-unix-new) and [`g_io_add_watch`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-IO-Channels.html#g-io-add-watch)

Be aware that the GTK main loop (and [Gtk Input and Event Handling Model](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-input-handling.html)), i.e. [GtkApplication](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkApplication.html) and the related [`g_application_run`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GApplication.html#g-application-run) or the older [`gtk_main`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html#gtk-main) are an [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) around some multiplexing system call like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (or the older [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)) and you probably need that loop to be aware of your pipes. When some data arrives on the pipe, you probably want to [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) it (and then call some GtkTextBuffer insert function).

You should make design choices: do you want the GUI interface and the other process to run concurrently? Or is the other `exe` process always so quick and with a small output (and no input) that you might just use `popen`?

On current GUI applications, the event loop should run quickly (at least 30 or 50 times per second) if you want a responsive GUI app.

Look also for inspiration inside the source code of some existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) GTK application (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/) or from your Linux distro).

Comment: Nice answer. I haven't used GTK other than for trivial "hello world" programs, so I didn't know about any of these functions.